# How to convert Rows to Columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've a table `Columns`

[image]

and a second table `Response` in which all data is saved.

[image]

Now I want to create a SQL View in which the result should be like this

[image]

I tried using pivot

```
select UserId ,FromDate, ToDate, Project, Comment
from
(
  select R.UserId ,R.Text , C.ColumnName
  from [Columns] C
  INNER JOIN Response R ON C.Id=R.ColumnId
) d
pivot
(
  max(Text)
  for ColumnName in (FromDate, ToDate, Project, Comment)
) piv;
```

but that didn't worked for me, I also referred this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server but was not able to implement it. Any ideas how to achieve the same in SQL View?

**Scripts for Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Columns](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Columns] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

insert into [Columns] values('FromDate',1)
insert into [Columns] values('ToDate',1)
insert into [Columns] values('Project',1)
insert into [Columns] values('Comment',1)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Response](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [bigint]  NOT NULL,
    [ColumnId] [bigint]  NOT NULL,
    [Text] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Response] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
insert into [Response] values(1,1,'1/1/2012',1)
insert into [Response] values(1,2,'1/2/2012',1)
insert into [Response] values(1,3,'p1',1)
insert into [Response] values(1,4,'c1',1)
insert into [Response] values(2,1,'1/1/2013',1)
insert into [Response] values(2,2,'1/2/2013',1)
insert into [Response] values(2,3,'p2',1)
insert into [Response] values(2,4,'c2',1)
insert into [Response] values(2,1,'1/1/2014',1)
insert into [Response] values(2,2,'1/2/2014',1)
insert into [Response] values(2,3,'p3',1)
insert into [Response] values(2,4,'c3',1)
insert into [Response] values(3,1,'1/1/2015',1)
insert into [Response] values(3,2,'1/2/2015',1)
insert into [Response] values(3,3,'p4',1)
insert into [Response] values(3,4,'c4',1)
```

Comment: first of all - You must fix main query - select UserId ,FromDate, ToDate, Project, Comment
from
(
  select R.UserId ,R.Text , C.ColumnName
  from [Columns] C
  INNER JOIN Response R ON C.Id=R.ColumnId
) d

it is wrong - it has different number of columns, You need add criteria for convert TEXT to projects and comments, possible using CASE, and then start transform result table

Comment: @a_vlad : ok, could you please show me how that can be done?

Comment: I don't know - how there start chat, because code in comment look bad, but it not full answer so not ready public it as final answer

   select R.UserId  AS ID,
    CASE WHEN r.ColumnId = 1 THEN
     R.Text
    END AS FromDate,
    
    CASE WHEN r.ColumnId = 2 THEN
     R.Text
    END AS ToDate,

    CASE WHEN r.ColumnId = 3 THEN
     R.Text
    END AS Project,

    CASE WHEN r.ColumnId = 4 THEN
     R.Text
    END AS Comment


   from [Columns] C
   INNER JOIN Response R ON C.Id=R.ColumnId

Comment: all simple if have 1 more column - sequence number of project for selected user, in other case need to do how to split user #2 for 2 separate

Comment: @a_vlad: what you said in query, I already tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: yes, but at least this query - work, included in question - not work and never will work - still good to start from correct queries. think - about my next question - how You will know p3 or p2 start 01/01/2013? if You resolve this question - it possible to go forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not explaining why your PIVOT query did not work for you, although it is not too hard to guess if your `Response` sample is representative enough of the data in that table in general. You have two sets of responses for User 2 but your query picks up only one.

As your expected output shows you want the query to return both sets, you need to teach it to distinguish between various sets of answers by the same user. One way is to use the ROW_NUMBER analytic function:

```
SELECT
  UserId,
  FromDate,
  ToDate,
  Project,
  Comment
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      r.UserId,
      r.Text,
      c.ColumnName,
      SetNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.UserId, r.ColumnId ORDER BY r.Id)
    FROM
      dbo.Columns AS c
      INNER JOIN dbo.Response AS r ON c.Id = r.ColumnId
  ) AS derived
  PIVOT
  (
    MAX(Text)
    FOR ColumnName IN (FromDate, ToDate, Project, Comment)
  ) AS p
;
```

The query above makes a few assumptions:

- every set of answers consists of the same set of ColumnIds;
- related responses are arranged together (based on the order of `Id`), or, at least, if one `FromDate` response comes later than another `FromDate` response, then its related `ToDate` response also comes later than the `ToDate` response related to the previous `FromDate`.

If there are special cases in the real data (e.g. some sets may be incomplete), a different approach may be required.

Answer (score -2):

I've done something similar in MySQL but I'm sure you could make some changes to make it work for your need. 
Take a look at 
http://knowittoall.blogspot.com/2011/09/converting-data-attribute-to-table.html
and
http://knowittoall.blogspot.com/2011/09/converting-data-attribute-to-table_18.html

Comment: Please try to add some details to the answer, it will help more.